# Gerar imagem transparente através de um formulário

Tags: php, gd

Olá.

Quero criar um formulário com um campo do tipo input e o outro como submit.

Quando escrever algo no campo input e clicar no botão submit uma imagem será gerada através da biblioteca GD do PHP. Mas o problema é, que eu não sei como posso fazer isso, já pesquisei em diversos fóruns e li vários artigos sobre, mas não consigo de jeito nenhum.

**CÓDIGO HTML**

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Texto a ser Gerado" size="100"/>
<input type="submit" value="Criar Imagem"/>
```

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```
<?php
//Define o header como sendo de imagem
header("Content-type: image/png");

// Definições
$preto = imagecolorallocate($i, 0,0,0); #Cor do texto; "cor preta"
$texto = "Exemplo"; #Texto a ser escrito
$fonte = "trebuc.ttf"; #Fonte que será utilizada

//Escreve na imagem
imagettftext($i, 32, 0, 160,360, $preto, $fonte, $texto);

//Gera a imagem na tela
imagejpeg($i);

//Destroi a imagem para liberar memória
imagedestroy($i);
```

?>

Por favor, me dê uma solução para o meu problema, como posso resolver isso?

Muitíssimo obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você pode fazer algo do tipo:

### index.html

```
<form action="arquivo_gera_imagem.php" method="post">
     <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Texto a ser Gerado" size="100"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Criar Imagem"/>
</form>
```

### arquivo_gera_imagem.php

```
<?php
//Define o header como sendo de imagem
header("Content-type: image/png");

$i = imagecreatefrompng('IMAGEM.png');    

// Definições
$preto = imagecolorallocate($i, 0,0,0); #Cor do texto; "cor preta"
$fonte = "trebuc.ttf"; #Fonte que será utilizada
$texto = $_POST["nome"];

//Escreve na imagem
imagettftext($i, 32, 0, 160,360, $preto, $fonte, $texto);

//Gera a imagem na tela
imagejpeg($i);

//Destroi a imagem para liberar memória
imagedestroy($i);
?>
```

Note que no arquivo index.html eu corrigi o form, fechando a tag, setando o method para POST e incluindo no action o nome do arquivo de destino.

No arquivo arquivo_gera_imagem.php eu troquei o valor da variável $texto para o que vem no post $_POST["nome"]

Comment: Fiz tudo como você mandou, mas não obtive resultado com o código. Ao escrever algo no campo input e clicar no botão submit gera algo desse jeito. i.imgur.com/pnqNppo.png — Mas não gera a imagem com o texto que inserir no campo input, espero a sua ajuda. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Vou verificar novamente.

Comment: @TruX o que vocÊ está recebendo na variável $i ?

Comment: Você precisa carregar uma imagem inicial para isso, $i = imagecreatefromjpeg('imagem_initial.jpg');